# Lookup displaying JavaScript error (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, lookup, soap, internet-explorer

One of our user is receiving a JS alert when filling a lookup (from a custom object).

```
error: {
    faultcode: 'soapenv:Client',
    faultstring: 'Attribute "xmlns" bound to namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" was already specified for element "query".',
}
```

The custom objet is really standard, no custom JavaScript, nothing. The user is using Internet Explorer. I think the error is triggered when there's a request sent to display a list of suggestion in the small popup (under the lookup).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a custom Visualforce page or the standard Salesforce UI?

Comment: Standard Salesforce UI

Comment: Is this IE 8.0 by any chance? I think there was a known issue about this. Can you try with IE9 or other browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue with IE8 from what I have seen.

Some relevant links from the force.com boards.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Problems-with-Enhanced-Lists-and-calling-Apex-from-Button/td-p/176150

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Other-Salesforce-Applications/AJAX-8-0-error-Attribute-quot-xmlns-quot-was-already-specified/td-p/36381

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Problems-with-Enhanced-Lists-and-calling-Apex-from-Button/td-p/176150

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Other-Salesforce-Applications/AJAX-8-0-error-Attribute-quot-xmlns-quot-was-already-specified/td-p/36381

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Javascript-button-error-Attribute-was-already-specified-for/td-p/253905

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Other-Salesforce-Applications/namespace-quot-already-bound-quot-problem/td-p/38061

Answer (score 1):

;-) ;-) this can be fixed by installing [Chrome Frame for IE](http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true) and adding the registry key/value string:

`OptInUrls` = `*` inside `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\ChromeFrame`

Comment: :) IE 8 should be outlawed. I wonder how much heartache we will get when IE10 is released widely.